# Easy way to collect multiple attributes of objects from a list

Tags: dictionary, collections, attributes, java-stream

If I've got a list of objects that has multiple attributes of the same type, what is the best way to collect all attributes of the list?

```
        class Issue {

            Long id1;
            Long id2;
            
            //with appropriate getters
        }
```

```
        List<Issue> is = //some list of Issue

        // Is there a better way to do the following? 

        Set<Long> allIds = is.stream().map(i->i.getId1()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        allIds.addAll(is.stream().map(i->i.getId2()).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mapMulti`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) if you're on at least Java 16 or [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) otherwise;

```
is.stream()
    .mapMulti((issue, mapper) -> {
        mapper.accept(issue.getId1());
        mapper.accept(issue.getId2());
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Or:

```
is.stream()
    .flatMap(issue -> Stream.of(issue.getId1(), issue.getId2()))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this. Use `mapMulti` to put each `long` on the stream.  Of course, since you're using a `set`, duplicates will be ignored.

```
Set<Long> allIds = is.stream().<Long>mapMulti((issue, consumer)-> {
            consumer.accept(issue.getId1());
            consumer.accept(issue.getId2());
  }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: I don't think you need `<Long>` there.

Comment: @DavidConrad  Unfortunately you do.  MapMulti requires type witnessing when mapping from one type to another.   But I double checked and removed it and it would not compile without it.  But there may be other ways but this is how I have always done it.

Comment: That's odd, I tried it on JShell from the early access version of JDK 21 and it works fine without it. Maybe they've improved type inference in later versions.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, don't get caught up in using streams or any other "sexy" way of doing a task when an imperative solution works and is easy to understand.  Remember that under the hood, the API makes use of imperative constructs. The following is probably the simplest and most efficient solution to accomplish your task.

```
Set<Long> allIds = new HashSet<>(); 

for (Issue issue : issueList) {
      allIds.add(issue.getId1());
      allIds.add(issue.getId2());
}
```